# ArangoDB key value to store Google certificates

Tags: google-api, key-value, arangodb, foxx

how do I use promised key value storage in ArangoDB?
I want to store [Google Certificates](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs) in ArangoDB in most effective way or better - most convenient way, which would be associative array resp. key-value. But i can not find anything about it in database.

Solutions I came up with are to make one document which would be wtorage for all keys and I'd acces it like `db.Certificates.document('certificates')[hash]` and second is to store documents like `db.Certificates.insert({'_key': hash, 'value': '.... google certificate ....'})` which would I access as `db.Certificates.document(hash).value`

I don't like those solutions since they don't seem right, values are one level deeper as I'd expect from key-value storage. Or is there any faster way to store certificates? Maybe somehow in RAM instead of db storage? I need them to be accessible across all callings of my foxx application and change them when they expire.
Thanks.

Comment: Are these keys issue to frequent changes? If no, why not simply have it inside the foxx service source code?

Comment: Yes they change, i guess, once a day.

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Comment: You suggested solution I was already aware of, but i was looking for something better.

Comment: do volatile collection suit your needs? Can you mark Alans answer as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the data to be persistent, you can use a volatile collection instead. Volatile collections will never be synced to disk so documents (but not the collection itself) will be lost between restarts -- but they are quite a bit faster because the data only lives in RAM.

You can create a volatile collection like a regular collection by passing the `isVolatile` option:

```
var db = require('org/arangodb').db;
var volatileCollection = db._create('temp', {isVolatile: true});
```

You can find more information in the chapter on creating collections: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/javascript-api/@arangodb/db-object/#db_createcollection-name--properties--type--options

Answer (score 1):

No, Collections are absolutely the way to go.

You would parse the json using `JSON.parse()`, then iterate and save them like this

```
db.certificates.save({_key: hashkey, value: certificate})
```

and later on fetch it using AQL:

```
FOR cert IN certificates FILTER _key == '<hashkey>' RETURN cert
```